# Mirror a public site using Nginx server

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-proxy

At work some websites are blocked (oa. Netflix) using some kind of blacklist for prohibited sites. I think the mechanism for blocking these sites is due a custom DNS server. Computers at work are fully locked down and no software can be installed.

I have a private public facing NGINX webserver (Debian) which I can fully customise. My private server is accessible from work.

Is there a way to mirror a site like Netflix through my NGINX server so I can acces it at work?

I have tried to create an extra custom `.conf` like:

```
location /netflix {
    proxy_pass http://netflix.com/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

But this does not work. How can I mirror sites through my NGINX webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace it with this:

```
     location /netflix {
        # internal;
         proxy_pass http://netflix.com/;
         proxy_set_header X-SERVER-PORT $server_port;
         proxy_set_header X-SERVER-ADDR $server_addr;
         proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-REAL-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

I don't know if you still need it but i noticed your post today so at least i tried to help.

EDIT: I changed URL to match yours. (netflix)

Comment: Does not quite work yet. I've created a new .conf file. 'https://example.com/netflix' gives me a 404, 'https://example.com/netlfix//' returns nothing.